# Mongodb: Query over several collections

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I've an `Application` collection with documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "TAIS",
    "commonUserName" : "TAIS",
    "scopes" : [
        DBRef("Scope", "GEN_ECO"),
        DBRef("Scope", "GEN_PRE")
    ]
}
```

So, `Scope` collection documents are like:

```
{
    "_id" : "GEN_PRE",
    "code" : "1DPVE000"
}
```

Here, there's another third collection, `Reference`:

```
{
    "_id": "sdfls2",
    "app" : "TAIS"
}
```

I need to build a query in order to look up `references` where have been `reference.app belongs to a given %scope%`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$lookup` to "join" collections.
e.g.

```
db.applications.aggregate([
{
 $lookup:
   {
     from: "third_collection",
     localField: "_id",
     foreignField: "app",
     as: "app_with_reference"
   }
  }
])
```

More:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup

Comment: Please provide the basic points of the provided url in your answer.

Comment: I dn't quite figure out, how do you relate `applications` with `scopes` and `references`?

Comment: I need to get all references where its `app` belongs to an given scope. Could you provide me a minial helping code?